# Promise.resolve object is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

I have an object with two methods.
`foo.publicMethod()` will call `foo.privateMethod()` internally.

For example:

```
foo.prototype.publicMethod = function() { 
   return this.privateMethod()
       .then(/* Do some other stuff */); 
};
```

In order to test the public method in isolation I am stubbing the private method, by making it return an empty promise.
For some reason, if I assign

```
foo.privateMethod = () => Promise.resolve();
```

everything works out fine, however doing

```
foo.privateMethod = Promise.resolve;
```

produces an error message: `TypeError: object is not a constructor`

I can't see how these two lines of code would produce a different result. Yes, one is technically wrapping `Promise.resolve` once, but I don't see how this should affect the end result. Any ideas what the difference might be?

Comment: *produces an error message* — when? where? That line by itself is not an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two are not exactly the same. In the working version the context of the `resolve` call is the `Promise` object. In the second version, the context is  whatever context `privateMethod` is called with, which would be `foo` when you call it as `foo.privateMethod()`.

To make sure you have the context set correctly with the second syntax, use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
foo.privateMethod = Promise.resolve.bind(Promise);
```

```js
function Foo() {}

Foo.prototype.publicMethod = function() { 
   return this.privateMethod(); 
};

var foo = new Foo();
foo.privateMethod = Promise.resolve.bind(Promise);

// Test it
foo.publicMethod().then ( _ => console.log('done'));
```

Comment: It's always `undefined` since `resolve` is defined in strict mode.

Comment: It's not necessarily undefined, if they are doing `foo.privateMethod()` then `this` would be `foo`.

Answer (score -1):

This is a mere guess but somewhere in your code you could be overwrititing `foo`, you first define it as a constructor function but then you overwrite it with an instance.

My guess is based on how you use `foo`, first you assign to its prototype

```
foo.prototype.publicMethod = ...
```

but then suddenly it is an instance

```
foo.privateMethod = ...
```

while one would expect

```
foo.prototype.privateMethod = ...
```

If somewhere later you try to use `foo`, which is an instance, as it is a constructor function:

```
var f = new foo(); // foo is not a constructor function
```

It could however be helpful to see the exact line that causes the issue, the assignment you show in two versions can't just end with the error message you posted.